# Magento 2 - ONLY the admin page doesn't work

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, htaccess

I have installed Magento 2 locally. I imported the database, changed the URL, and so on. Everything works fine - each subpage loads. Unfortunately, the admin doesn't work. The page just shows 404. This is just a 404 as if the page just wasn't there (eg localhost/blabla and localhost/admin show the same).

I changed the admin's address to "admin", I cleaned the cache - still the same. Everything works except the admin page.

Logs show no errors. I have a .htaccess file. Does anyone have an idea what else could be wrong?

PS. I found a solution. Old values (old address) remained in the database in some places in core_config_data. Of course, these values were only as secure_base_url / base_url (probably via the multistore).

Comment: did you confirm your admin value from app/etc/env.php file?

Comment: In your case it should be backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],

Answer (score 0):

`1. Flush and Clear Magento Cache by Command line`

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

rm -rf var/cache/*

rm -rf var/generation/*
```

`2. Enable Rewrite mod and configure htaccess file`
**Modify from:**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

**to:**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

`3. Replace the URL`
**This:**

```
http://localhost/index.php/adminUrl
```

**With:**

```
http://127.0.0.1/index.php/adminUrl
```

`4. Restart apache server`

I hope it helps